# How make node view return without menu?

Tags: 7, nodes

Perhaps the question is simple, but I can not understand how to return the body of a node without a menu.
I did a module that loads the content of node into the custom area.

```
function loadnode_in_region_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['load_node/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'loadnode_in_region_node_page_view',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

return $items;  
}

function loadnode_in_region_node_page_view($nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid, NULL, false);
    $vnode = node_view($node);
    return drupal_render($vnode);
}
```

JS looks like

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'load_node/' + id,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#ajax-result').html(data);
        },
    });
```

Result looks like this, with a duplicate menu
[image]

If I change line from

```
    return drupal_render($vnode);
```

to

```
    echo drupal_render($vnode); OR print drupal_render($vnode);
```

The result looks like I would like it, but some fields are not displayed correctly, such as voting and image. Looks as if they are not themed.
[image]

How to return themed node body without a menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can create tpl for the menu and render the content and design tpl as required or create tpl for the content type in theme

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that besides the menu the module re-adds scripts to the custom region. In fact, it adds the whole page. I tried to create **region--(r_description).tpl.php** but it does not replace formatting (the same situation as here [https://www.drupal.org/node/1200498](https://www.drupal.org/node/1200498)). Do you know another way how this can be done?